# Exercises with a Torn Wrist Tendon

Tags: exercise, strength, cardio, injury

For the past month, I noticed that I developed about a 1/2 inch size lump on my left inner wrist.  I suspected it was a cyst, but after seeing the hand surgeon I was told that I have a torn Flexor carpi radialis (FCR).

The doctor gave two options:

- 8 weeks in splint or
- 8 weeks in cast

I am pretty active with cardio (running, plyo) and weights but I am trying to determine the best option. No matter the choice I make, I want to still work out.

What are my options with this type of injury?  Are there any strength training, cardio choices with this type of wrist injury?

Just as a side note, any thoughts on cast or splint?

Comment: This question should be discussed with a professional, it basically isn't a fitness but a health question.

Comment: @Informaficker It was discussed with my doctor but I was also looking for feedback from others on what to do with this type of injury

Comment: I try to explain why I think it's problematic. Nobody here knows your specific situation, even if you describe it to perfect detail you will always get answer like "I had the same issue" although they didn't. Then even if you get the perfect answer to your specific situation it is very likely that you might read it wrong (thats a normal issue with all communication especially in textual form). And the third thing is that other people will come here, having the "same" issue and think whats written here is the only truth and saves them a visit to a doctor.

Comment: @Informaficker noted, I will keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: I'll err on the side of caution here and close the question. While I'm sure you might find some helpful information here, it's rather borderline for the site. I'm taking the responsibility of ensuring other users don't misuse what they read here as single truth as @Informaficker points out.

Comment: @MattChan feel free to delete this post since it doesn't meet the standards of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just curious, why was surgery to repair the tendon not an option?

As far as working out, I wouldn't worry about that too much, because that's a short term thing, unless you have a specific event (Your 'A' race for the season or something) that you are training for.

8 weeks is transitory, and yes, you might lose some fitness or a bit of muscle size during that time, but compared to a lifetime of activity, it's nothing. Whichever option gives you the BEST chance to get back to normal activity for the long term is the one that I would go with.

Just as a personal example: I've been a competitive athlete since I was 4 (40ish years), and was in the middle of the current triathlon season, and ruptured my achilles in martial arts class 6 weeks ago. I had the option of either cast only, and letting it knit on it's own, or surgery to repair. The surgery was a longer rehab, more inactivity, but it gives me the best option to return to full, normal activity.

So, figure out which option gives you the best chance to get back to normal, do that, and deal with the minor losses that you will have in 8 weeks.

Comment: He said that surgery would be the final option if the tendon does not heal with the splint/cast. The process will be splint/cast, then ultrasound therapy, then surgery if needed.

Comment: Ok, then that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this is probably one of the few instances in which using isolation exercises on machines is good. It's not something you'd want to make a habit of, but doing a leg press instead of a squat to keep working your legs would make sense, and one of those tricep machines that lets you push against a pad with your arm instead of gripping something would also work in the mean time.

Cast or splint would probably depend on personal discipline. If you know you'll not do anything with your wrist, then splint is probably more convenient, but if you know you won't be able to resist activity, getting the cast is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch! That seems serious. I'd take the surgery. I had the same, not as severe though and I had surgery done.  After the surgery I visited a physiotherapist for about a month and I was fine until I hurt my wrist really badly. And I had to go back to the physiotherapist. That was bad.

He gave me this thing, called a blood stimulation wrap. I put in on when I'm in pain. Plug it, let my hand rest. And when I take it off, poof, no pain. It's great. Look into getting one for after your surgery. The one I got is the [King Brand Wrist Injury Treatment](http://www.kingbrand.com/Wrist_Injury_Treatment.php).

So, definitely consider surgery. And be careful after, make sure your wrist is totally 100% or else it could knock you back a bit. Good luck. Happy holidays!

Comment: -1 for undisclosed refferal link

Comment: Can you explain why the King Brand wraps worked and what is it about them that helped in healing?

Comment: Well, Kingbrand works by promoting blood flow through the injured area. So if you have a stretched muscle, it will promote flow through the muscle. With a better blood flow, it allows the injury to be healed quicker. I got all this from the website. It promotes healing!! Hope it helps!

Comment: Feel free to edit your answer and add the information in.